# Pipe each row of csv into bash command

Tags: linux, bash

I have a single column CSV file with no header and I want to iteratively find the value of each row and count the number of times it appears in several files.

Something like this:

```
for i in file.csv:
 zcat *json.gz | grep i | wc -l
```

However, I don't know how to iterate through the csv and pass the values forward

Imagine that `file.csv` is:

```
foo,
bar
```

If `foo` exists 20 times in `*json.gz` and `bar` exists 30 times in `*json.gz`, I would expect the output of my command to be:

```
20
30
```

**Here is the solution I found:**

```
while IFS=',' read -r column; do
  count=$(zgrep -o "$column" *json.gz | wc -l)
  echo "$column,$count"; done < file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with a single `grep` operation treating `file.csv` as a *patterns* file (obtaining patterns one per line):

```
grep -f file.csv -oh *.json | wc -l
```

---

- `-o` - to print only matched parts
- `-h` - to suppress file names from the output

Comment: This gave me one number, which I assume is sum of each row count. What I would like is the total number of times that each row value in files.csv is found in *.json. So if there are 20 rows in files.csv, I want 20 counts, based on how many times each row value appears in *.json.

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate through output of `cat` run through subprocess:

```bash
for i in `cat file.csv`: # iterates through all the rows in file.csv
   do echo "My value is $i"; done;
```

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)